# How to fix 'encoding' issue in Python using vaderSentiment package

Tags: python, encoding, nlp, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am working on a sentiment analysis problem and found the vaderSentiment package but cannot get it to run. It is giving me an 'encoding' error.

I have tried adding 'from io import open' but that did not fix my issue. Please see code below.

```
from io import open
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def sentiment_analyzer_scores(sentence):
    score = analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)
    print("{:-<40} {}".format(sentence, str(score)))

sentiment_analyzer_scores("The phone is super cool.")
```

Here are the results I am wanting:

```
"The phone is super cool----------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.326, 'pos':         
0.674, 'compound': 0.7351}"
```

The results I am getting:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-bbb91818db04>", line 6, in <module>
analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

File "C:\Users\mr110e\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site
packages\vaderSentiment\vaderSentiment.py", line 212, in __init__
with open(lexicon_full_filepath, encoding='utf-8') as f:

TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace of the error. Without it we don't have enough to go on.

Comment: Updated the error.

Comment: python2 `open` doesn't provide the  'encoding' keyword argument, so you should use python3

Comment: Which version would you recommend downloading?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/issues/47) it also might help

Comment: The latest one is [3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/)

Comment: Thank you! Downloaded 3.7 and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vaderSentiment` package doesn't support python 2.

You should use [python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/) or [little bit edit the package's source code](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/issues/47)

Answer (score 0):

Open this file using a text editor

`<your python2 instalation path>\lib\site-packages\vaderSentiment\vaderSentiment.py`

Add these lines on the top of file:

```py
from io import open
#------------------
import os
import re
import math
import string
import requests
import json
from itertools import product
from inspect import getsourcefile
```